# javascript variable value into html:hidden value

Tags: javascript, struts, taglib

i'm adding dynamically struts taglib html:hidden field into javascript code.
So i have:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function addRow(index){
  var prezziSize = parseInt($('#prezziSize').val());
  var selectedValue = combo.options[combo.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
  ...
  var row='<html:hidden property="listaPrezzoForm['+prezziSize+'].idUAServizio" value="+selectedValue+"/>';
  ...
 $(row).appendTo(div); 
}
```

Even if both prezziSize and selectedValue are correctly valued, i cannot insert into the hidden field the selectedValue value, but just it's name i.e."+selectedValue+".
On the other hand the list index prezziSize is correctly written in the rendered page.

What am i messing with?

thanks 
bye

Comment: found out that the taglib code was interpreted by the server before calculating the value of "selectedValue". The solution was to use a standard html input type=hidden

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming combo is a select element

```
var combo = document.getElementById("combo");
```

Have you tried getting selectedValue by doing

```
var selectedValue = combo.options[combo.selectedIndex].value;
```

or

```
var selectedValue = combo.options[combo.selectedIndex].text;
```

Edit - unless that's fine and I misunderstood the question, this line may be incorrect, as well; you were missing 's wrapping value="+selectedvalue+" - should be value="'+selectedValue+'"

```
  var row='<html:hidden property="listaPrezzoForm['+combo+'].idUAServizio" value="'+selectedValue+'"/>';
```